# ZeroMQ: How to publish to a number of receivers except for one of them

Tags: zeromq, distributed-computing, messaging, pyzmq, low-latency

I have **`N`** subscribers to a Publisher. The message is a simple boolean value. The messaging pattern is slightly different from the regular **`PUB/SUB`** :

- When one subscriber receives a `true`, all the other subscribers are supposed to receive a `false`.

So I would love to publish a `false` to all but one subscriber. This exceptional subscriber is not fixed, but selected by user.

One idea I have right now is to **`PUB/SUB`** a `false` to all, then send a `true` to the exceptional subscriber with a **`PUSH/PULL`** or **`PAIR/PAIR`** pattern. But this feels like a hack.

Will there be an easy solution based on **`PUB/SUB`** pattern instead of looping through a 1-to-1 pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use topic filter at all. It's not sophisticated enough for what you want to achieve. So you'll have to have the filtering done by the application.

So if the PUB sends a message containing a single number, e.g. '3', so long as the SUB node that is #3 knows its own identity, it will get the message '3' and accept that as a "true" intended for itself.

Meanwhile all the other SUB nodes also receive the message '3', but know that they're not #3, and so interpret this as a false intended for themselves.

Where you may get into trouble is if the client PUB nodes have no way of knowing their own identity. But solving that sounds fairly easy with run time configuration. Another way would be to use XPUB/XSUB, and use the subscription message from XSUB to XPUB as a way for a client to "announce itself" to the PUB, but then immediately undo that to revert to a blank topic (so as to receive every XPUB message).

Comment: Wow. That sounds super convoluted. I think I'll probably just use a app-side logic to filter with a simple loop. Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: @kakyo Good luck!

Comment: Yes, "knowing" is just the first part of the problem, the next is to handle, if not avoided *weakly* if not un-*managed* at all "identity" duplicates, the next is how to detect an added node, the PUB is unaware about, that was not present so far, the next is how to detect a lost node, sending any future messages to is of no impact, yet the PUB is unaware of it. ( The subscription management, that is the topic). Anyway, if the implementation is not critical, sending a bit-field with one and only one bit ON, will work for naive, bit-position mapped signalling at the lowest costs possible **:o)**

Comment: @bazza BTW, does your **assumption to "*immediately undo that*"** hold? AFAIR, the topic-filter (now, in post v4.x+ API operated on (X)PUB-side) can have multiple (many) subscriptions, so having the first one being the ""-blank ( i.e. subscribe to anything ) + having the any next subscription topic the *{ id }* and / or whatever else, will still deliver all messages to this (X)SUB-side, as the ""-blank still does match any such message, doesn't it? So if we ignore the issues with management of dynamically (dis-)appearing peer-nodes' identities, the XPUB/XSUB is a free to use signalling channel

Comment: @user3666197, ah, you're right. If one can subscribe to multiple topics, then one of those topics can be for all (X)SUB nodes to receive all messages. UUIDs/GUIDs sound like a good way of ensuring there's no identity clash (i.e. '3' becomes '<guid string>'. As for lost nodes, whether that's a problem the OP will experience is uncertain; but perhaps regular resubscription by the client XSUB nodes could be used as a way of saying "I'm still here!".

Comment: Pleasure to hear you pieces of wisdom. As always, Salute, Sir!

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"Will there be an easy solution based on **`PUB/SUB`** pattern instead of looping through a 1-to-1 pattern?"*

Oh sure, there will.

Use **`XPUB/XSUB`** Archetype. Each **`XSUB`** starts with sending it's "***subscription***"-message, a `UUID#`-hash or likewise.

The **`XPUB`**, as it `.recv()`-s the `XSUB`-s "***subscription***"-message, registers a new peer, it's `UUID#`-hash and in cases, when it indeed wants to send some message to this very peer and no other now, it simply `.send()`-s such a message, having made the `UUID#`-hash put as a binary-prefix to it ( i.e. prepended "on the left" side of the actual message, as you know it from the `PUB/SUB` ), as this is the way the topic-filtering works.

So easy.
So cool...